NotAuthorizedOrNotFound Error while invoking OCI Rest APIs, am I missing something?
Running the below curl command gives error response.
"code" : "NotAuthorizedOrNotFound",
"message" : "Authorization failed or requested resource not found."
Note: I have trimmed parts of the OCIDs for anonymity
curl -v -X GET -sS https://iaas.eu-zurich-1.oraclecloud.com/20240925/instances -H "date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 13:45:48 GMT" -H "Authorization: Signature version=\"1\",keyId=\"ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaukzgxdsh2ellhjrvxd5yhenmwkkk7hv2ya/ocid1.user.oc1..aaaaaaaaytts6yfw4agjmg5x5qbgv42p57asjfxerma/3f:50:15:e1:2a:46:42:eb:70:a2:53:b9:1d:d3:c5:fd\",algorithm=\"rsa-sha256\",headers=\"(request-target) date host\",signature=\"iXn/4Lg5MXfeswEhb0p5s/Z52xAqjrRPGhiJhaTdkHi0UGZVNMLqY94cfZFPQDvPEAx6S9kjams+y1r4odUDtvk6CCJEIMZjISYQ9Z+wf8gREXeumXrOEiMDi52gJ1DK7Wbx+F2nywusy+bPQmzUKma9o7GUhtMvx0pv7zWRQQl+hzjesM9rXDbnKK+m83Ms/9OPmdbXoR+lQwodxzWThBZAVdA6WNdP7sypm/VGd/azZLyO9O9l/4gojYNGvwLxRWTztaE+t+IFbSe3MPKH1qaLLT5oemi7HdgokPy4WOhvsGsz9I9RgAuHrTg8kcwVBhDO7XPCqPz3mP41lNXBZw==\""
* Host iaas.eu-zurich-1.oraclecloud.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 140.204.16.201
*   Trying 140.204.16.201:443...
* Connected to iaas.eu-zurich-1.oraclecloud.com (140.204.16.201) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /20240925/instances HTTP/1.1
> Host: iaas.eu-zurich-1.oraclecloud.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 13:45:48 GMT
> Authorization: Signature version="1",keyId="ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaukzgxdsh2ellhwfscwi6aaftglyik2rjrvxd5yhenmwkkk7hv2ya/ocid1.user.oc1..aaaaaaaaytthajcanl7s2pu67tats6yfw4agjmg5x5qbgv42p57asjfxerma/3f:50:15:e1:2a:46:42:eb:70:a2:53:b9:1d:d3:c5:fd",algorithm="rsa-sha256",headers="(request-target) date host",signature="iXn/4Lg5MXfeswEhb0p5s/Z52xAqjrRPGhiJhaTdkHi0UGZVNMLqY94cfZFPQDvPEAx6S9kjams+y1r4odUDtvk6CCJEIMZjISYQ9Z+wf8gREXeumXrOEiMDi52gJ1DK7Wbx+F2nywusy+bPQmzUKma9o7GUhtMvx0pv7zWRQQl+hzjesM9rXDbnKK+m83Ms/9OPmdbXoR+lQwodxzWThBZAVdA6WNdP7sypm/VGd/azZLyO9O9l/4gojYNGvwLxRWTztaE+t+IFbSe3MPKH1qaLLT5oemi7HdgokPy4WOhvsGsz9I9RgAuHrTg8kcwVBhDO7XPCqPz3mP41lNXBZw=="
>
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 13:49:09 GMT
< opc-request-id: /44842409ED5F847D8B836D95C1F0D419/C1F45CFA4F2F827A597974134A782935
< Content-Type: application/json
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
< Content-Length: 111
<
{
  "code" : "NotAuthorizedOrNotFound",
  "message" : "Authorization failed or requested resource not found."
}* Connection #0 to host iaas.eu-zurich-1.oraclecloud.com left intact

I'm new to this so not sure if I'm missing something. Any advice?

Can you try using OCI CLI instead ?
